# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement') by ViewChildren unit tests

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine

My unit test doesn't pass because of this error: "Failed: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')". I think that the problem is incorrect mocking of ViewChildren, but I don't know how do it right. Can someone please help to fix it?

ts

```
@ViewChildren('locationInput') inputs: QueryList<ElementRef>;
addCity(): void {
this.items = this.locationForm.get('items') as FormArray;
if (this.regionSelected && this.checkIfAllCitysAreSelected()) {
  this.items.push(this.createItem());
  this.quantityOfLocations++;
  this.cdr.detectChanges();
  const tempInput = this.inputs.toArray()[this.quantityOfLocations - 1].nativeElement;
  this.tempAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(tempInput, this.localityOptions);
  this.tempAutocomplete.setBounds(this.regionBounds);
  this.tempAutocomplete.setOptions(this.localityOptions);
  this.autocomplete.push(this.tempAutocomplete);
  this.addEventToAutocomplete(this.quantityOfLocations - 1);
}
```

}

spec.ts

```
 it('method addCity should add new item and add autocomplete', async(() => {
  let array: FormGroup[] = [];
  array.push(mockedForm);
  let formArray = new FormArray(array);
  component.locationForm = new FormGroup({
   items: formArray
  });

  const spy = spyOn(component, 'addEventToAutocomplete');
  spyOn(component, 'checkIfAllCitysAreSelected').and.returnValue(true);
  component.regionSelected = true;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  component.inputs[1] = new ElementRef({ nativeElement: { value: 'fake' } });
  component.addCity();

  expect(component.quantityOfLocations).toBe(1);
  expect((component.locationForm.controls['items'] as FormArray).length).toBe(2);
  expect(component.tempAutocomplete).toBeTruthy();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
 }));
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

The problem occurs with the changes on ViewChildren element.
It can be solved easily just by instead of:

```
@ViewChildren('locationInput') inputs: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

to:

```
@ViewChildren('locationInput', {static: true}) inputs: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

It should solve your problem.

Comment: A couple things: 1. `@ViewChildren` does not possess the `static` metadata property (perhaps it did when you wrote this in 2022?). However, it does have `enableDistinctChangesOnly` which seems to be sorta similar. This property is deprecated, will be removed and permanently set to true soon. 2. Perhaps OP's use case means that `static/enable...` should *not* be true. This, then, is a poor solution that only patches the test but does not solve the real problem.

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren#:~:text=emitDistinctChangesOnly